# Input mask is not firing in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net

i have input mask set for each textbox that is not firing.

but script javascript is firing fine.

code is copy pasted from another page of same website and page which get copied is working fine

Comment: It would help if you can post the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Copying and Pasting DOES NOT mean that something will work straight out of the box. Even when you download someone's source code it is not guaranteed to work 1st time every time.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what js library are you using orwhat is your problem without any code, but I am showing what I use and how I use to do the input mask

I use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and a plugin called [masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

All you need to is to include the two js libraries into your page

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

than just call them

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
       $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
       $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");          
    });
    </script>
```

supposing you have this textboxes

```
<input id="date" type="text" />
<input id="phone" type="text" />
```

It will automatically do input mask for you

Comment: I use it too, it's actually a very easy going plugin (stand alone)...
That you are able to use without any problem.